# background problems with android 4.4.2 in specific activities

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having few activities ,in which there is at least 1 button.in few of them,when I try to set the color of the button to green(statically in the xml), the button doesn't appear during play(but if I change its text color I can see its text. and I can also click on it). when I use a phone with android 5 it works well ,but when I use android 4.4.2 it doesnt. any ideas about it ?
this is one of the problematics xml:

```
              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/activity_finger_cam"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context="com.example.gilad.takepicture.FingerCamActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="373dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="נא לא להזיז את האצבע עד לסיום."
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewAlert"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:text="CAPTURE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_weight="0.37"
            android:onClick="onClick" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `when I try to set the color of the button to green(statically in the xml)` how exactly are you doing that?

Comment: android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" inside the button xml.